# Libgdx scene 2d ui localization

Tags: libgdx, localization, scene2d

I'm Libgdx begginner.

I'm trying to make game menu using scene2d UI.

Once the english version is completed, I am now going to create korean, japanese and chinese version.

but... asian letters are not visible or comes out strange..

So I checked the font using bitmapfont (following codes)

< at constructor >

```
 font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("skin/lotte.fnt"), Gdx.files.internal("skin/lotte.png"), false);
```

< at draw method >

```
game.batch.begin();
font.draw(game.batch, "안녕하세요?", gameViewport.getWorldWidth()/2,gameViewport.getWorldHeight()/2);
game.batch.end();
```

Above korean letters works well. But It is not working for scene2d UI skin.

Does scene2d UI skin not support asian letters?

Comment: Sounds like a texture filtering issue, but can't be sure without seeing screen shots.

Comment: Are you loading the same font inside your skin? It's just a bitmap font that is stored in the skin so they "should" behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

the problem comes out reading the string from I18NBundle.

the following code has the problem,

```
Label titleLabel = new Label(bundle.get("strings/test"), skin, "lotte2", Color.BLACK);
tbl.add(titleLabel).padBottom(stage.getHeight()/20f).row();
```

but this code works well.

```
Label titleLabel = new Label("ㄱㄴㄷㄹㅁㅂㅅ", skin, "lotte2", Color.BLACK);
tbl.add(titleLabel).padBottom(stage.getHeight()/20f).row();
```

Thanks for "Tenfour04" & "Madmenyo" !